# How do Epicor Mobile POS Systems connect to the Database/Middleware in the Store?

Tags: mobile, point-of-sale, epicor

How do Epicor Mobile POS Systems connect to the Database/Middleware in the store? Do they connect via a RESTful API or do they use some other method? There's practically no information available about Epicor. And we need to do preliminary planning for a possible integration for a customer that uses Epicor.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the product but for Epicor ERP it depends on the version, the REST interfaces were added at E10.1.500 as a preview and generally available after that. Before this version, the access would have been through the WCF interfaces as used by the smart client to connect to the application servers. Earlier versions (E9) are similar, but have reduced support.

If they are using cloud servers these are automatically patched to the latest version and the access will be via REST.